# git interactive rebase is missing lines in zsh

Tags: git, shell, intellij-idea, zsh

When I do an interactive rebase and want to edit commits (rewording, squashing, etc), the top lines of the "file" are cut off, and I cannot cursor or scroll up to see them. Also, the

A brief example:

```bash
git rebase -i HEAD~1
```

Which gives this correct output (shortened ... for conciseness)

```bash
r 1777bf7 Some test commit message

# Rebase 9d2434a..1777bf7 onto 9d2434a (1 command)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# ...
```

Then, on the next screen I'd expect to see the original commit message and be able to reword the commit. Instead, I get the page but with missing top lines:

```bash
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# Date:      Thu Feb 22 15:54:09 2024 -0500
# ...
```

and, trying modify this causes strange behavior. If I go into "Insert" mode and try to add to the first line, the original commit message appears. It's almost as if the lines are stacked in the first few rows, and the commit message is hidden. (Here, I typed the `b` character:

```bash
bSome test commit message message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# Date:      Thu Feb 22 15:54:09 2024 -0500
#
```

A similar thing happens with squashing commmits - the top rows of the file are cut off, until I try to edit them.

Has anyone encountered this, and knows how to fix? I have no special zsh settings in my `.zshrc`. I use the terminal in IntelliJ and also iTerm, but only see this in IntelliJ's terminal.

Comment: [This](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/edit-project-history.html#interactive-rebase) might be a better way of accomplishing what you're trying to do in IntelliJ.

Comment: Agree with Bill, any reason why you avoid ui? Also, which ide version are you using? Are you using the new terminal?

Comment: I've always used the CLI for git - not necessarily avoiding UI, but I could ask the same to anyone using it why they're avoiding CLI. Everyone has their preferences.
I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.4 (Ultimate Edition). Not sure what you mean by new terminal - I am using the "new" IntelliJ UI.